# Firefox stops responding to mouse events after moving window

Tags: windows-7, firefox, 64-bit, troubleshooting, mouse-click

I've been dealing with this issue now for a few weeks and I've tried everything I can think of to resolve it, but nothing seems to work.

Sometimes, when I open Firefox, and start moving the window it will stop responding to mouse events, and it will lock up Explorer (i.e. the Desktop and Taskbar no longer respond to mouse events either) until I close Firefox. The issue occurs randomly and I can never repeat it when I want to. Sometimes I might have to repeat the exact same actions over and over again 5-6 times before it'll happen.

So far, I've tried...

- Logging off / restarting
- Launching Firefox with add-ons disabled
- Launching with a fresh profile
- Unchecking "use hardware acceleration when available"
- Making sure I was on the latest version of Firefox
- Even tried upgrading to latest NVIDIA driver
- ...and yes, of course I've searched on Google

At first, I thought it might be related to my graphics driver because I realized most of the time it was happening right at the moment part of the window went over to my second monitor, so I tried upgrading to the latest NVIDIA driver, but that had no impact. I have since noticed it doesn't seem to matter whether I'm moving the window over to the other monitor or not. I just need to move the window anywhere and it will happen. I've also on rare occasions seen it happen just from clicking on a bookmark folder in the Bookmarks Toolbar.

Aside from re-installing Firefox or possibly even reinstalling Windows (neither of which I want to do), I'm all out of ideas. Has anyone seen this issue before or have any additional ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by doing **both** of the following:

- Delete `%APPDATA%\Mozilla` and all sub folders and files.
- Delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Mozilla` and all sub folders and files.

Doing one without the other was not sufficient to resolve the problem. I had to do both as that the same time.